# Android App keeps crashing when performing user authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I've built an app for user authentication.
My app is crashing when I'm calling a setOnClickListener with Intent filter.
MainActivity.Java:

```
package com.example.passiveincome;

import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText emailId, passwd;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView signIn;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.ETemail);
        passwd = findViewById(R.id.ETpassword);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        signIn = findViewById(R.id.TVSignIn);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String emailID = emailId.getText().toString();
                String paswd = passwd.getText().toString();
                if (emailID.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Provide your Email first!");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                } else if (paswd.isEmpty()) {
                    passwd.setError("Set your password");
                    passwd.requestFocus();
                } else if (emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!(emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty())) {
                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, paswd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                        "SignUp unsuccessful: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(I);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The crash is happening when I'm transitioning from MainActivity class to LoginActivity class.

LoginActivity class:

```
package com.example.passiveincome;



import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText loginEmailId, logInpasswd;
    Button btnLogIn;
    TextView signup;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        loginEmailId = findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        logInpasswd = findViewById(R.id.loginpaswd);
        btnLogIn = findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);
        signup = findViewById(R.id.TVSignIn);
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent I = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(I);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent I = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(I);
            }
        });
        btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String userEmail = loginEmailId.getText().toString();
                String userPaswd = logInpasswd.getText().toString();
                if (userEmail.isEmpty()) {
                    loginEmailId.setError("Provide your Email first!");
                    loginEmailId.requestFocus();
                } else if (userPaswd.isEmpty()) {
                    logInpasswd.setError("Enter Password!");
                    logInpasswd.requestFocus();
                } else if (userEmail.isEmpty() && userPaswd.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fields Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!(userEmail.isEmpty() && userPaswd.isEmpty())) {
                    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPaswd).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Not sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }
}
```

Here is the log file with error only:

```
2021-09-13 20:24:21.222 11737-11776/com.example.passiveincome E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2021-09-13 20:24:26.961 11737-11737/com.example.passiveincome E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.passiveincome, PID: 11737
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.passiveincome/com.example.passiveincome.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
        at com.example.passiveincome.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The app crashes before I could see the LoginActivity layout.

Comment: Try [adding your activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities#:~:text=To%20declare%20your%20activity%2C%20open&text=The%20only%20required%20attribute%20for,class%20name%20of%20the%20activity.) to your manifest file. Let me know how this works.

Comment: Exactly, it is very clearly mentioned in the log itself

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes , this issue is solved , thanks to @AliasCartellano.